# ErrorDialogFragment.show does not work

Tags: android

Im making a android app and now trying to connect my app to GooglePlay but the documented code does not work.

```
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    // Create a fragment for the error dialog
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
    // Pass the error that should be displayed
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
}
```

At this code, the dialogFragment.show emits a error saying,

The method show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String) in the type ErrorDialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)

I dont understand why this is a problem.... there is no such android.app.FragmentManager... help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incorrect version of `DialogFragment`. Basically, you have 2 versions of the following classes :

- DialogFragment
- Fragment
- FragmentManager
- ...

There is one version that is only available for API 11 or above, using the package `android.app` and one version from the support library with package `android.support.v4.app` (the version can change, for some classes it could come from v7 like `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` for example).

The key point here is that they cannot be mixed, you either use the android.app version or the support library but if you do use the support library, you have to use all the classes from it.

Short answer :

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment;
```

or

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't explain how to use ErrorDialogFragment, which doesn't seem to exist in the support lib.

Comment: It does exist, I'll edit the answer. **EDIT** Here u go